# convert data from Firebase RTDB

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm expecting my random value to be an int but I got a String instead,
is this the right way to do it.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('RandomVal').onValue,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
      final event = snapshot.data as DatabaseEvent;
      final data = event.snapshot.value as Map;
      print(data['Value']);   // my value as expected
      print(data['Value'].runtimeType);   // String instead of int 
    }
    return Text('please wait');
  },
),
```

Comment: Try` int.parse(data['Value'])`

Comment: it worked thanks but is it the only way. why can't we just set the type in the RTDB just like Firestore

Comment: The Realtime Database returns data as the JSON type it was stored as. Since it returns the value as a string, most likely you stored it as a string. If that is not the case, edit your question to show the relevant JSON data as it is stored in the database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Oh I see, my mistake I was using 'Value' as String now its working thanks